# Linear Algebra applications to differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra

This is I guess a rookie question. In the Gilbert Strang's textbook Introduction to Linear Algebra, he mentions the following in section 6.3: Applications to Differential Equations.
$ du/dt = u $ is solved by $ u = e^t$ and $ \frac{du}{dt}= \lambda u$ has solutions $ u(t) = Ce^{\lambda t}$

Shouldn't the answer be $0.5u^2 $? My sincerest apologies if I am missing something obvious. Many thanks in advanced.

Comment: The function in question is a function of variable $t$.

Answer (score 1):

No: to solve for $u$ by integration you would need to integrate with respect to $t$, giving $u=\int u dt$. There is no reason for this to be $u^2/2$ or for that matter $t^2/2$.

Answer (score 1):

You may already know that the function $e^t$ is famous because its derivative is equal to itself so when you solve the equation 
\begin{align}
\frac{d u(t) }{dt}=u(t)
\end{align} the answer must be $u(t)=e^t$.
Now similarly you find for the equation 
\begin{align}
\frac{d u(t) }{dt}=\lambda u(t)
\end{align}
that the answer is $u(t)=Ce^{\lambda t}$ since for any constant $C$ you find 
\begin{align}
\frac{d u(t) }{dt}=\frac{d Ce^{\lambda t}}{dt}=\lambda C e^{\lambda t}=\lambda u(t)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Here $u$ is a function of $t$. That is, you look for a solution of the differential equation of the form $t\mapsto u(t)$. The long form of the equation in the book is

$$
u'(t)=\lambda u(t),
$$

for which the book gives the right solution.
What you solved is the equation

$$
u'(t)=t.
$$